# How to Connect Spheres from center in Processing?

Tags: 3d, processing

Currently I'm trying to connect spheres that are close within a set distance. I tried using the line(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2) function but that creates somewhat random lines. I then tried to use beziers, but I'm still getting weird results.

Here's the code so far:

```
import peasy.*;

ArrayList<Position> positions;
int count=0;
int distanceToDrawLines = 20;
PeasyCam camera;

void setup() {
  size(1280, 720, P3D);
  stroke(255);
  positions = new ArrayList<Position>();
  smooth(8);
  lights();
}

void draw() {  
  float randomX, randomY, randomZ;
  //camera(mouseX, height/2, (height/2) / tan(PI/6), width/2, height/2, 0, 0, 1, 0);
  //camera = new PeasyCam(this, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  randomX = random(0, width);
  randomY = random(0, height);
  randomZ = random(0, 40);

  Position newPosition = new Position(new PVector(randomX, randomY, randomZ), 20);
  positions.add(newPosition);
  fill(255, 0, 0, 75);
  stroke(0);
  newPosition.Draw();


  for (int i=0; i<positions.size(); i++) {
    Position position = positions.get(i);
    noFill();
    beginShape();
    vertex(position.vector.x,position.vector.y,position.vector.z);
    if (position!=newPosition) {
      float d = dist(position.vector.x, position.vector.y, position.vector.z, newPosition.vector.x, newPosition.vector.y, newPosition.vector.z);

      if (d<=distanceToDrawLines && d!=0) {
        println(d, positions.size(), position.vector, newPosition.vector);
        bezierVertex(position.vector.x, position.vector.y, position.vector.z, newPosition.vector.x, newPosition.vector.y, newPosition.vector.z);
      }
    }
    endShape();
  }

}
```

And the `Position` class:

```
public class Position {
  public PVector vector;
  private boolean drawn;
  public float radius;

  public Position(PVector vector, float radius) {
    this.vector = vector;
    this.radius = radius;
  }

  public void DrawSphere() {
    if (!drawn) {
      fill(255, 0, 0, 75);
      noStroke();
      translate(vector.x, vector.y, vector.z);
      sphere(radius);
      fill(0);
      stroke(0);
      drawn = true;
    }
  }

  public void DrawEllipse() {
    if (!drawn) {
      fill(random(0,255), random(0,255), random(0,255), 75);
      noStroke();
      ellipse(vector.x, vector.y, radius, radius);
      point(vector.x, vector.y);
      fill(0);
      drawn = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "somewhat random lines"? Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted the Position class so I'll assume it roughly looks like this:

```
class Position{
  PVector vector;
  float radius;

  Position(PVector pos,float rad){
    vector = pos;
    radius = rad; 
  }

  void Draw(){
    pushMatrix();
    translate(vector.x,vector.y,vector.z);
    sphere(radius);
    popMatrix();
  }

}
```

There are a couple of things that don't seem to reflect your intentions:

1. You're not clearing the background when drawing a new frame. This may result in lines all over the place as you rotate the camera as the frame buffer isn't cleared.
2. The camera is currently commented out and should probably be initialised once in `setup()` rather than multiple times per frame in `draw()`
3. Generating spheres multiple times a second can get costly to render and a bit chaotic to make sense on: I suggest limiting the number of spheres generating initially. Perhaps that was the intent of your `count` variable ?
4. this part:

> spheres that are close within a set distance

sound a bit unclear. It doesn't look like that distance is set, since one of the distances you're comparing against in the most recent Position instance which is at a random location. (Unless you actually do want to compare distance to the most recent sphere/Position instance)

Other than that, I just have a few hints that simplify this setup:

1. using positive and negative ranges for randomised values will help 'centre' the sphere distribution(since positive values only will make the group shifted to the right)
2. Making use of [PVector's dist()](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_dist_.html) which does the same thing as

   dist(position.vector.x, position.vector.y, position.vector.z, newPosition.vector.x, newPosition.vector.y, newPosition.vector.z);
   but keeps the syntax a bit cleaner: `position.vector.dist(newPosition.vector);`

You can try these suggestion in a revised and commented version based on your code (use up/down keys to change distance threshold):

[image: Spheres with distance based rendered lines]

```
in-processing
import peasy.*;

ArrayList<Position> positions;
int count=0;

//increase the distance threshold value: with a wider range of random values there will be less chances of spheres being so close to each other
int distanceToDrawLines = 200;
PeasyCam camera;

//keep a reference to the most recent Position instance
Position newPosition = null;

void setup() {
  size(1280, 720, P3D);
  stroke(255);
  positions = new ArrayList<Position>();
  smooth(8);
  lights();

  //use simplified spheres (will look blockier, but will render faster)
  sphereDetail(5);
  //setup PeasyCam once in setup
  camera = new PeasyCam(this, 100);
  camera.setMinimumDistance(50);
  camera.setMaximumDistance(500);
}

void draw() {  
  background(127);

  //generate a limited amount of spheres
  if(count < 100){

    float randomX, randomY, randomZ;
    randomX = random(-width, width);
    randomY = random(-height, height);
    randomZ = random(-40, 40);

    newPosition = new Position(new PVector(randomX, randomY, randomZ), 20);
    positions.add(newPosition);

    count++;
  }


  for (int i=0; i<positions.size(); i++) {
    Position position = positions.get(i);

    noFill();

    if (position != newPosition) {

      float d = position.vector.dist(newPosition.vector);

      if (d<=distanceToDrawLines && d!=0) {
        println(d, positions.size(), position.vector, newPosition.vector);
        line(position.vector.x, position.vector.y, position.vector.z, newPosition.vector.x, newPosition.vector.y, newPosition.vector.z);
      }
    }else{
      //hightlight newest Position instance in transparent red
      fill(255, 0, 0, 75);
    }
    //render every Position instance (after the noFill() / fill() have been set
    position.Draw();

  }

}
//test - play with UP/DOWN arrows to tinker with distance
void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == UP) distanceToDrawLines += 10;
  if(keyCode == DOWN) distanceToDrawLines -= 10;
  distanceToDrawLines = constrain(distanceToDrawLines,20,2000);
  println("distanceToDrawLines: " + distanceToDrawLines);
}

class Position{
  PVector vector;
  float radius;

  Position(PVector pos,float rad){
    vector = pos;
    radius = rad; 
  }

  void Draw(){
    pushMatrix();
    translate(vector.x,vector.y,vector.z);
    sphere(radius);
    popMatrix();
  }

}
```

Update here is a sample highlighting some of the optimisation concepts mentioned in the comments. Ideally, some of the code would move to a shader, but it's worth using `jvisualvm` to track down what calls are currently taking most of the time to execute and start optimising there.

```
import peasy.*;

ArrayList<Position> positions;
Position newPosition;
int count=0;
int distanceToDrawLines = 500;
PeasyCam cam;

PShape nodes;

int fcount, lastm;
float frate;
int fint = 3;

void setup() {
  size(1280, 720, P3D);
  positions = new ArrayList<Position>();
  smooth(8);
  lights();

  //use simplified spheres (will look blockier, but will render faster)
  sphereDetail(0);//5
  frameRate(60);
  cam = new PeasyCam(this, 100);
  cam.setMinimumDistance(50);
  cam.setMaximumDistance(500);

  nodes = createShape(GROUP);

  while (count < 300) {
    float randomX, randomY, randomZ, randomRadius;
    randomX = random(-width*2, width*2);
    randomY = random(-height*2, height*2);
    randomZ = random(-1000*2, 1000*2);
    randomRadius = random(10, 40);
    newPosition = new Position(new PVector(randomX, randomY, randomZ), randomRadius);
    positions.add(newPosition);
    count++;
  }
  println("positions initialized");

  //calculate distances once, rather than multiple times per seconds
  //similarly instantiate geometries, which will simply be rendered in draw() 
  float distanceToDrawLinesSq = distanceToDrawLines * distanceToDrawLines;
  int numPositions = positions.size();
  for (int i=0; i<numPositions-1; i++) {
    for (int j=i+1; j<positions.size(); j++) {
      Position iPosition = positions.get(i);
      //iPosition.DrawSphere();
      nodes.addChild(getSphere(iPosition));
      Position jPosition = positions.get(j);
      //jPosition.DrawSphere();
      nodes.addChild(getSphere(jPosition));
      //cam.lookAt(iPosition.vector.x, iPosition.vector.y, iPosition.vector.z, 5);
//      float d = iPosition.vector.dist(jPosition.vector);
//      if (d <= distanceToDrawLines) {
      //using distance squared (more useful in draw() than setup though
      float dSq = PVector.sub(iPosition.vector,jPosition.vector).magSq();
      if (dSq <= distanceToDrawLinesSq) {

        PShape line = createShape(LINE,iPosition.vector.x, iPosition.vector.y, iPosition.vector.z, jPosition.vector.x, jPosition.vector.y, jPosition.vector.z);
        line.setStroke(color(255));
        line.setFill(false);
        nodes.addChild(line);

        //stroke(255);
        //line(iPosition.vector.x, iPosition.vector.y, iPosition.vector.z, jPosition.vector.x, jPosition.vector.y, jPosition.vector.z);
      }
    }
  }
  println("geometries initialized");

}
PShape getSphere(Position p){
    PShape sphere = createShape(SPHERE, 1.0);
    sphere.setStroke(false);
    sphere.setFill(p.fillColor);
    sphere.translate(p.vector.x,p.vector.y,p.vector.z);
    sphere.scale(p.radius);
    return sphere;
}
void draw() {  
  background(0);

  hint(DISABLE_DEPTH_TEST);

  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2, height/2, -500);
  rotateY(frameCount * 0.01);
  rotateX(frameCount * 0.01);

  shape(nodes);
  popMatrix();

  hint(ENABLE_DEPTH_TEST);

  fcount += 1;
  int m = millis();
  if (m - lastm > 1000 * fint) {
    frate = float(fcount) / fint;
    fcount = 0;
    lastm = m;
    println("fps: " + frate);
  }

  //saveFrame("/output3/sequence####.tga");
  //saveFrame in separate thread
  TImage frame = new TImage(width,height,RGB,sketchPath("frame_"+nf(frameCount,3)+".tga"));
  frame.set(0,0,get());
  frame.saveThreaded();
}

class TImage extends PImage implements Runnable{//separate thread for saving images
  String filename;

  TImage(int w,int h,int format,String filename){
    this.filename = filename;
    init(w,h,format);
  }

  public void saveThreaded(){
    new Thread(this).start();
  }

  public void run(){
    this.save(filename);
  }

}

public class Position {
  private float speed;
  public PVector vector;
  public float radius;
  public int fillColor = color(200, 0, 0, 75);

  public Position(PVector vector, float radius) {
    this.vector = vector;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.speed = 0.05;
  }

  public void DrawSphere() {
    noStroke();
    vector.x+=random(-speed, speed);
    vector.y+=random(-speed, speed);
    vector.z+=random(-speed, speed);
    fill(fillColor);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(vector.x, vector.y, vector.z);

    sphere(radius);
    popMatrix();
  }

  public void DrawEllipse() {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(vector.x, vector.y, vector.z);
    ellipse(vector.x, vector.y, radius, radius);
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

[image: updated sphere draw sketch]

Comment: I've added the Position class.

Comment: Also, the `distanceToDrawLines` is the variable that is used to check if the spheres are this variable apart to draw the line. Makes sense? Sorry for the late reply...

Comment: Have you tried the code I posted above (and read the notes) ?

Comment: Not yet, will give it a look when I get home and mark it as answer. :)

Comment: I've managed to make it how I wanted it. Quick question though. If they are about 500 spheres the camera movements are very slow. Is there something I can do to improve the framerate? [GitHub link](https://github.com/robertiagar/playing-with-ellipses)

Comment: Frumos ! Initially I was looking at dist() called which could be turned into a less computationally expensive distance squared version. However, after looking into CPU usage using ```jvisualvm``` I noticed the sphere tessellation and rendering in Processing is quite costly. An ellipse that is always pointing at the camera will look a lot like flat single colour sphere. Ellipse still has plenty of vertices though. I recommend having a look at the [PShader tutorial](https://www.processing.org/tutorials/pshader/), especially the billboarding part in section 10. Bafta!

Comment: If I save each frame and animate the camera, it still jitters, but if I render out the frame in something like After Effects, It's smooth as butter!

Comment: I recommend using ```jvisualvm``` to sample/profile CPU usage and optimise your code based on what's taking up most of the time. Start with the sphere rendering and use billboards as I suggested above. Move the ```while``` loop in ```setup()```, thread image saving so it doesn't block the animation/render thread (see the TImage class in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124039/exporting-a-gif-from-a-processing-sketch-w-gif-animation-library/22133355#22133355) for a hint), etc. I also suggesting asking a separate question to keep things tidy over here :)

Comment: @RobertIagar I've added a code sample based on my comments above